# Rails (PG::GroupingError: ERROR: column must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, deployment, pg

In my local this query work perfect with sqlite3

```
 def Event.most_like
   select("events.*, count(like_events.event_id) as likes_count")
   .joins(:like_events).group(:event_id).order("likes_count 
    DESC").limit(4)
 end
```

but i got some error when deploy heroku
`PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "events.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

Can someone help me fix this?

Comment: How does this work on development?. It shouldn't. You use an aggregate function without grouping by all non-aggregate fields. Do you need to select events.*? Can't you just select event_id? Anyway, can you show the sql statement run on Heroku?

Comment: oh thank you so much but i fixed it by adding `.group("event_id")`

Answer (score 1):

As the message, all fields in `Select` clause must appear in the `GROUP BY` or in aggregate function. In this case, you select all fields of `Event` so that the fields, which includes `events.id`, need to satisfy above requirement.

To fix that, I suggest to change function to select only event's id and likes_count as below:

```
def Event.most_like
  select("events.id, count(like_events.event_id) as likes_count").
  joins(:like_events).
  group('events.id').
  order("likes_count DESC").
  limit(4)
end
```

If you still need to get event records, you can fetch those records based on their ids.