# How do I group all of the objects on my model by a column on the same model without using a join model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a model `Position` which has the following schema:

```
# Table name: positions
#
#  id                :bigint           not null, primary key
#  action            :integer
#  current_price     :float
#  current_value     :float
#  status            :integer          default("0")
#  ticker            :string
#  volume            :integer
#  created_at        :datetime         not null
#  updated_at        :datetime         not null
#  portfolio_id      :integer
#  stock_id          :integer

  belongs_to :portfolio
  belongs_to :stock
```

My `User` model looks like this:

```
  has_one :portfolio, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :positions, through: :portfolio, dependent: :destroy
```

My `Portfolio` model looks like this:

```
class Portfolio < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :positions
end
```

What I would like to do is return all of the positions of the `current_user` all grouped by the `ticker` of the `position`, without having to do a `join` on the `stock` model, as an array or some AR object that I can iterate over and list each AR object within each group.

The way I was able to successfully do it is this:

```
@positions = current_user.positions.buy.open.order(transaction_date: :desc)
@grouped_stocks = @positions.joins(:stock).group_by { |ps| ps.stock.ticker }
```

But, ideally I would like to just do it on the first query alone.

I tried the following, but they all don't work.

```
current_user.positions.buy.open.group("ticker")
=> #<Position::ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation:0x3ffdf189d6d4>

current_user.positions.buy.open.order(transaction_date: :desc).group("ticker.name")
      Position Load (2.9ms)  SELECT "positions".* FROM "positions" INNER JOIN "portfolios" ON "positions"."portfolio_id" = "portfolios"."id" WHERE "portfolios"."user_id" = $1 AND "positions"."action" = $2 AND "positions"."status" = $3 GROUP BY ticker.name ORDER BY "positions"."transaction_date" DESC  [["user_id", 2], ["action", 0], ["status", 0]]
  Position Load (2.3ms)  SELECT  "positions".* FROM "positions" INNER JOIN "portfolios" ON "positions"."portfolio_id" = "portfolios"."id" WHERE "portfolios"."user_id" = $1 AND "positions"."action" = $2 AND "positions"."status" = $3 GROUP BY ticker.name ORDER BY "positions"."transaction_date" DESC LIMIT $4  [["user_id", 2], ["action", 0], ["status", 0], ["LIMIT", 11]]
=> #<Position::ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation:0x3ffdefe0a7a4>
```

How do I do that?

**Edit**

See a sample screenshot below of how I want the results to be organized:

[image: screenshot-of-data-layout]

Comment: Is there any column called ticker in `positions` table? If not how will you group without joining?

Comment: Yes there is, look in the schema table at the top of the question for `positions`.

Comment: `ticker` is a column in positions, where does `tickers.name` come from?

Comment: @SebastianPalma good point. That's wrong. I updated the question to remove it. It still returned a similar AR Association Relation object, which doesn't help me much.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? What about `current_user.positions.buy.open.select('distinct on (positions.ticker) *')`?

Comment: PostgreSQL. So that query returns some items, but it doesn't return all of the `positions` with the same ticker. It only returns 1 per ticker, whereas I need all of them.

Comment: _What I would like to do is return all of the positions of the current_user all grouped by the ticker of the position_ - you want the user positions grouped by their position ticker, but anyway want all of them? Seems there's a contradiction there.

Comment: Yeah I know it's a bit confusing, so I just updated the question with a screenshot of how it should be grouped. Basically, each position belongs to a ticker, but there can be many positions within each ticker or only 1 position. So if there are multiple positions, it should show all positions grouped under that 1 position. Refresh the question to see the screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

I see you have `ticker` on the positions table and not the `stocks` table. So you don't need to look at the `stocks` table if that is the case. (probably better to have it on the stocks table)
also `transaction_date` isn't listed above so I assume it is on the `positions` table.

This is more or less what you had I am assuming the `group('ticker.name')` was not working right for you as you need to group by the `positions` tables `ticker` column.

```rb
@positions_grouped_by_ticker = current_user.positions.buy.open.group('positions.ticker').order(transaction_date: :desc)
```

Using `group` will return you an array of arrays, not an AR collection.

```
# view.html.erb
@grouped_positions.each do |stock_positions|
  <%= render stock_positions %>
end
```

Comment: When I tried this, it doesn't work. `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "positions.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT "positions".* FROM "positions" INNER JOIN "portfolios...`

Comment: Ah, I see!  I've updated the query above. This person had a similar problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/48369842/1861295